# Tensorflow clamp values outside specific range

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have been using tensorflow to implement a Convolutional neural network,
I have a requirement that the the output values be less than a given value **MAX_VAL**

I tried creating a matrix filled with **MAX_VAL** and then using **tf.select** and **tf.greater** :

```
filled = tf.fill(output.get_shape(),MAX_VAL)
modoutput = tf.select(tf.greater(output, filled), filled, output)
```

But this doesn't work because the shape of output is not known statically:
It is [?, 30] and tf.fill requires an explicit shape.

Any idea how do i implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an alternative solution that uses [`tf.fill()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/constant_op.html#fill) like your initial version. Instead of using [`Tensor.get_shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor.get_shape) to get the static shape of `output`, use the [`tf.shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#shape) operator to get the dynamic shape of `output` when the step runs:

```
output = ...
filled = tf.fill(tf.shape(output), MAX_VAL)
modoutput = tf.select(tf.greater(output, filled), filled, output)
```

(Note also that the [`tf.clip_by_value()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#clip_by_value) operator might be useful for your purposes.)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do it.

Instead of using **tf.fill** I used **tf.ones_like**

```
filled = MAX_VAL*tf.ones_like(output)
modoutput = tf.select(tf.greater(output, filled), filled, output)
```

Please mention if there is a faster or better way to do this is possible.